# a map with contractible domain must be nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map between top spaces $X$ and $Y$. Is the following true?

If $X$ is contractible then $f$ must be nullhomotopic.

Here is an argument:

Since $X$ is contractile then $id_X\simeq c$ where $c:X\to X;x\mapsto *_X$. Let 
$H_t:X\to X$ be  this homotopy, that is, $H_0=id_X$ and $H_1=c$. then the map
$G_t:X\to Y; x\mapsto f\circ H_t(x)$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $c':X\to Y; x\to *_Y$.

I don't see what is wrong with this argument since it can't be true knowing that $I$ is contractible hence all loops are nullhomotopic which implies that all fundamental groups are trivial!!

Comment: A loop has  a circle $S^1$ as domain , not   $I$. So homotopy theory is not trivial, after all...

Comment: yes but this is the same thing as a map with domain $I$ sending $1$ and $0$ to the basepoint. So yes it is a map with domain $I$

Comment: This was my original thought as well, and then I realised what you said about maps from $S^1$ being special kinds of maps from $I$ and didn't have time to think it through to ineff's conclusion below. Thinking of loops as maps from $S^1$ means you don't have to put extra conditions on the map and also means you can avoid relative homotopy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proof is correct and also your conclusion is correct too, because every loop is homotopic to the null path as *continuous function*.
The point is that the homotopy that you have created is a homotopy of continuous functions but not a homotopy of paths because it doesn't fix the starting and the ending point during the deformation of the path. To do that you should have used a [homotopy relative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Relative_homotopy) to the set $\{0,1\} \subset [0,1]$, and an homotopy of this type doesn't exists.

Hope this help.